# Update Pandas df Given String Query

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-loc

As a result of data introduced by users in the interface I have a string query-like.

```
query = '(ColA=="7") & (ColB=="3") & (ColC=="alpha") & (ColD=="yu")'
```

Now I want to update a column of the df based on those conditions, assigning it a variable Z.

I don't know if it can be done somehow with `loc`

```
df.loc[query, 'ColZ'] = Z
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution by myself:

```
df.loc[df.eval(query), 'ColZ'] = Z
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html

Comment: eval is a dangerous coding practice. query method is better

Answer (score 5):

Yes that can be done with `query`

```
df.loc[df.query(query).index,'ColZ']=Z
```